# Control my phone via Chrome over 3G/4G

Tags: remote-control

My end goal, is to be able to control my phone using my Chrome on my desktop when they're not on the same network. I've seen AllCast, which only seems to be able to work when the devices are on the same network.

Does anybody know of anyway I can do with just over 3/4G?

The one restriction I have is it must be doable just using a Chrome App as I don't have install rights on the PC I need this for.

From everything I've found so far they all need to be on the same network.

A few years ago I used to be able to do this with an old Jailbroken iPhone, and using RealVNC on the PC, but so far the only VNC solutions I can find only work Android to PC, rather than PC to Android

Comment: Well, I don't really think you can do that as there's isn't any chrome extension available. But still if you want to remotely control most of the working then you can try installing AirDroid app over your device and see if that does something you are trying to do !

Comment: I'll take a look at AirDroid now, thanks for the tip :)

Comment: No problem at all ! Also let me know if this fix your problem !

Comment: Unfortunately AirDroid won't work, the website is blocked at work.

Comment: I can't understand why the website is blocked and all? Are you trying to access your network over a restricted network ??

Comment: Yeah, it's the firewall at work which restricted it.

Comment: Well, if that's the case then I don't think any of the tool can helps as your firewall will keep blocking the remote connection to work properly! So, I would say it would be better if you configure your firewall to made an exception over the usage of the AirDroid connection. or if that's not possible then I guess it would be better to wait a little while for other members to respond over this one as I am running out of options over here!

Comment: Yeah I don't think it's gonna be possible :(. It was just something I was hoping to do, but in no way needed. Thanks for all your suggestions though :)

Comment: If like me, you came looking for a way to remote control your android phone and were considering AirDroid .. please beware and have a look at http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/12/09/airdroid-beta-4-0-0-2-fixes-major-security-issues-official-rollout-expected-soon/ before you commit to it